Cannot enable recursive directory scanning in paperless NGX consume folder
I am running the latest version of Paperless-ngx (PNGX) in Docker on a windows PC. (Standard installation using Paperless-ngx supplied script).
When I start PNGX, it successfully ingests any file placed in my 'consume' folder but will:

not periodically check for new files; or
ingest any in sub-folders within the consume folder.

I have amended my docker-compose.env file to include PAPERLESS_CONSUMER_RECURSIVE=true and PAPERLESS_CONSUMER_POLLING=600 as directed in the documentation.
I have stopped and restarted the PNGX container, and also tried closing the Docker Application and rebooting the PC), but it does not solve the problem.

Hi - found the really simple answer was that I had to delete and re-compose the docker container after making changes to the docker-compose.env file.  It  is not sufficient to restart the paperless container stack.  Hope this helps someone else.
